# We will get bashed if we did that

Tags: grammar

> *We will get bashed if we **did** that*.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? I am somewhat confused with the sentence structure.

To be more specific, I just want to make sure if the usage of 'did' here is correct. Is it also possible to say 'do'?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but this is getting close to a proofreading question. What are you concerned about, specifically? (To my eyes, the sentence is OK, if somewhat informal).

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically correct. It basically means that if you're about to do what you plan on doing, you would definitely get beaten or harshly criticized ("bashed" can mean both of those things).

As you wrote, it doesn't sound a hypothetical situation. If you use "if + past tense + will", you are sure that there are going to be consequences. But if you use "if + past tense + conditional (would), that means that you're uncertain as to the outcome.

Comment: "would" is subjunctive, not conditional, and doesn't necessarily imply uncertainty. You'd use "might" to imply that.

Comment: It's also possible to use do here, right?

Comment: Your first paragraph is mistaken. Your second paragraph sets out the two possibilities well, but (as your second sentence shows)  "if we did that" referring to the future takes *would*.

Comment: I would say _either_ "We would get bashed if we did that" (conditional) _or_ "We will get bashed if we do that (in the future)".

Comment: @KateBunting; As Ameen pointed out, there is a third possibility: "If we did that [in the past] then we will be bashed [in the future, as a consequence]".

Comment: @TimLymington I can't understand why 'if' would be used in that context, since we _know_ whether or not we did 'that'.

Comment: @Kate:  Semantics is independent of grammar...  But *we* might refer to a company, where the directors don't know everything employees do.